# JSTL: Check if Submit was clicked

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

How can I check if the Submit button was clicked in JSTL?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the button has a `name` attribute so that when it's pressed, an associated request parameter will be submitted. For JSTL, it then becomes as simple as checking any other request param: `${param.nameOfTheButton}`.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can check if the submit button was clicked or not using JSTL.
But you can know which submit button was clicked inside a servlet etc...
for example if the button is

```
<input type="submit" name="Go"/>
```

for jsps use ${param.Go} 
for servlets use request.getParameter("Go");

Comment: Hi, this was already answered by kschneid :) The normal way would be to give his answer an upvote if you agree. But you don't have a 15 reputation yet (which is minimum required to be able to vote on other's answers). I'd suggest to go post *new* answers on questions rather than duplicating the already given answers. Then you'll quickly earn enough reputation :)